Transpilation error: CircuitError: 'The amount of qubit(0)/clbit(0) arguments does not match the gate expectation (2).'
I am trying to implement a algoritm that reduces the number of qubits required for MAXCUT optimization. I need to create a custom gate that encodes a diagonal unitary matrix where the diagonal elements are exp(i pi R(theta)), where R(theta) converts the continious parameter theta to 0 if theta in [0,pi] ot 1 if in [pi,2pi]. This makes that our diagonal al the end is composed of 0s and 1s. I created a custom gate using the following code:
qc = QuantumCircuit(self.num_qubits)

        unitary_array = np.zeros([len(self.params), len(self.params)], dtype=complex)
        for i, theta in enumerate(self.params):
            if 0<= theta < np.pi:
                unitary_array[i, i] = 1
            if np.pi <=theta <2*np.pi:
                unitary_array[i, i] = -1

        diagonal_matrix = Operator(unitary_array).to_instruction()
        qc.append(diagonal_matrix)

        self.definition = qc

This code is encoded in a class object so I don't have problems with the logical operations and ParameterVectorElement class.
Once called this class and appended to the circuit, it gives me no error, however, when I transpile the circuit to the AerSimulator(), I get the error:
CircuitError: The amount of qubit(0)/clbit(0) arguments does not match the gate expectation (2).

I should say that the matrix is 4*4 (4 diagonal parameters) and my example has 2 qubits.
I would appreciate it greatly if anyone could help me or give me any suggestion so thata I can transpile my circuit correctly.
I also append the transpilation code:
qc = QuantumCircuit(N)
for i in range(N):
    qc.h(i)
qc.append(diagUGate,[i for i in range(N)])
param_assign = {thetas[i]:np.pi/2 for i in range(n)}
qc.assign_parameters(param_assign, inplace=True) 
qc.draw()
simulator = AerSimulator()
qc_transpile = transpile(qc,backend=simulator)

N is the number of quabits and n is the number of nodes in the MAXCUT graph. In my example: N = 2 and n = 2. The diagonalUgate is a diagonal gate like the one shown in the image:

Where the R is defined in the beginning of the question.

Can you share the code that tries to transpile your circuit? It looks like you are handing over zero qubits.

I edited the question and added the code for the transpilation.

Sorry, I should have been more precise. To understand the problem, I think a minimal working example would be necessary. You might be cutting out lines of code that cause the error. It is almost impossible to diagnose only from snippets. For instance, I don't know which value is assigned to $N$, or what is diagUGate, could be the class you are referring to earlier or an instance thereof, or something completely different.

Okay, i added the definition and some extra information. Thanks in advance!

I would say it is pretty much impossible to debug your code and provide some guidance unless you provide what is needed to run it. For instance, you are not providing any of the imports required, you are using things like self.num_qubits, which makes me think this code is inside some sort of class, but you haven't specified any of these details. As @RefikMansuroglu says, you should provide a minimal working sample code that can be replicated by others.
